# Simulink Datastore hierarchy

Tags: matlab, simulink, hierarchy

I know that I can access variables defined at the top level anywhere in the model. Is it possible to access a variable defined at the lower level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/data-store-basics.html)

> You can define two types of data stores:
>
> A local data store is accessible from anywhere in the model hierarchy
>   that is at or below the level at which you define the data store,
>   except from referenced models. You can define a local data store
>   graphically in a model or by creating a model workspace signal object
>   (Simulink.Signal).
>
> A global data store is accessible from throughout the model hierarchy,
>   including from referenced models. Define a global data stores only in
>   the MATLAB® base workspace, using a signal object. The only type of
>   data store that a referenced model can access is a global data store.